# Makefile objects from .c .cpp and .S sources

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am facing a problem with my makefile. I am trying to compile .c; .cpp and .S files from ./src/. The objects should go into ./obj/ and the binaries into ./bin/. With my current file, it tries to searches for files in ./src/, but tries to compile objectfiles for each extension. So for example, if it finds kernel.cpp, it will try to compile kernel.S and kernel.c, but they are not there, so i get an error.

Here is my code:

```
TARGET = kernel

CC = gcc
LD = ld

SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = obj
BINDIR = bin

SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c) $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.S)
HDR = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.h)
OBJS = $(SRCS:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o) $(SRCS:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o) $(SRCS:$(SRCDIR)/%.S=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
rm = rm -f

ASFLAGS = -m64
CFLAGS = -m64 -Wall -g -fno-stack-protector -nostdinc
LDFLAGS = -m elf_x86_64 -Ttext=0x100000

$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

$(OBJS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.S
    $(CC) $(ASFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(rm) $(OBJS)

.PHONY: remove
remove:
    $(rm) $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
```

I might try to separate SRCS into SRCS_Cpp and so on... But i don't know if that's the best solution. I am pretty new to makefiles^^

I think i found the solution^^

```
TARGET = kernel

CC = gcc
LD = ld

SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = obj
BINDIR = bin

SRCS_c = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
SRCS_cpp = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
SRCS_S = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.S)
HDR = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.h)
OBJS = $(SRCS_c:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%_c.o) $(SRCS_cpp:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%_cpp.o) $(SRCS_S:$(SRCDIR)/%.S=$(OBJDIR)/%_S.o)
rm = rm -f

ASFLAGS = -m64
CFLAGS = -m64 -Wall -g -fno-stack-protector -nostdinc
LDFLAGS = -m elf_x86_64 -Ttext=0x100000

$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/%_c.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/%_cpp.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/%_S.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.S
    $(CC) $(ASFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(rm) $(OBJS)

.PHONY: remove
remove:
    $(rm) $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
```

Is there something i do wrong? I am trying to compile a kernel without the use of a cross-compiler^^

Comment: It appears you have found an answer to the issue you described. Is there still a question that you need answered?

Comment: Well i have a lot of questions, but not about makefiles^^ Except maybe about automake, but i don't think that i will need it.